# vim syntax highlighting weirdness

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have some specific settings for my latex highlighting and am using the indentLine plugin, which requires `let g:indentLine_fileTypeExclude = ['tex', 'bib']` to avoid the [conceal feature annoyance](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine/issues/78). Anyway, when I start vim with `vim filename.tex` my vimrc gets loaded properly, but when I simply call `vim` and then open a given tex file, it'll ignore the `vimrc`.

Any idea what's causing it? Also, let me know what information you need, as I am far from certain on what would be needed.

EDIT:
Okay so I've found that for both cases i'm in a [tex] environment, but if I'm in a [plaintex] environment then the weirdness doesn't happen. If that helps anyone.

2nd EDIT:
New development, it is only the first file that's opened that seems to ignore the exclusion for indentLine, the remainder are shown exactly as they ought to.

Answer (score 0):

The `plaintex` is a separate *filetype* in Vim (cp. `:help ft-plaintex`), so you need to add it to the IndentLine config:

```
let g:indentLine_fileTypeExclude = ['tex', 'plaintex', 'bib']
```

**Edit** This now looks like a command ordering issue. It's hard to remotely troubleshoot this, as the exact plugins and their initialization order may be important. Please capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for the ordering of commands (but it might be difficult to see what's happening in a potentially vast list of commands).

It might be sufficient to just reload the *first* file that has those problems, with `:e!`.

Comment: Well plaintex wasn't giving an issue it was just `tex`. I added plaintex to the list of excludes but unfortunately it didn't change anything. I've updated the question with new findings on the issue (that it's only the first tex file that's opened that has this issue, the rest are loaded correctly).